# Svelte use compiler cloned from GitHub

Tags: github, compiler-construction, svelte, svelte-3

I know this message might sound stupid.
But I'm trying to play around a bit with the Svelte Compiler from GitHub https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte. I cloned and installed everything just like in the Instructions. But how can I now use the compiler to run a Project I programmed in Svelte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a local version of a project in another project with [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

In the case of Svelte, you also need to ensure that you rebuild after any change (to Svelte). You can generally find the build script in the scripts section of `package.json`. For Svelte, it's `npm run build`, or `npm run dev` to watch & rebuild as you change.

```sh
git clone git@github.com:sveltejs/svelte.git svelte
cd svelte
npm install
npm link
npm run dev # watch & rebuild
```

In another terminal:

```sh
npx degit sveltejs/template my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm link svelte # <--------- here
ls -l node_modules | grep svelte # confirm svelte is a symlink
npm run dev
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to link the local version of your repositories:

In the Svelte repository:
`npm link`
In the project repository:
`npm link svelte`
(this should give some feedback where you see you are linking to a local version)

This should setup your project to use the local version of Svelte

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

Comment: Thank you very much.